# Is there Javascript keydown restriction while changing browser url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I tried to add a keydown event with javascript that refreshes page. But it did not work. The same code works perfectly on button click event. How to achieve reloading page with keydown event? The page needs to be loaded with GET, even if the page first was loaded with POST, so window.location.reload() doesn't work.

This issue is happening with FF 4. I haven't tried other browsers yet.

The code that does NOT work is:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        window.location.href = document.URL;
  }
});
```

This code works perfectly:

```
$('.my-button-class').click(function(){
    window.location.href = document.URL;
});
```

Comment: I've just tried it with chrome and it's working. What browser are u using?

Comment: I'm using FF 4.
 
Added the browser to my question, should have done it in the first place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using "e.which" instead of "e.keyCode".  Browsers vary on that issue, but jQuery makes sure that "which" can  be used reliably to get the key code.

*edit* — Firefox 4 does seem to act funny, but you can work around the behavior by reloading the page in a new event:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = document.URL;
        }, 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm catching the key correctly. The problem is browser is not refreshing the page. But thanx, this might prove useful with other browsers.

Comment: @MadSysop OK well I think I found a workaround for you - I'll update my answer.

Comment: BTW, you can use 0 as the setTimeout parameter. No need for 1 millisecond pause :D

Comment: Yes I know but it's an old habit :-)  Glad it worked!  It's a trick that I usually save for IE.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything wrong with your code. Test it out on this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yWAqD/

Alternatively, you could try `which`. The below code should tell you which one works for you.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      alert('keyCode')
      window.location.href = document.URL;
      return true;
  }

  if (e.which == 13) {
      alert('which');
      window.location.href = document.URL;
  }
});
```

**EDIT**  : You need to hit 'ENTER' in the jsfiddle page to test this code. Make sure you hit enter while you're in the 'Result' pane.

Also, as @Pointy points out (no pun intended), `which` is a guaranteed way to do this. The above code just helps you find where your problem lies.

Comment: jQuery ensures that "which" will always be the key code; there's no need to try the "keyCode" property at all.

Comment: @Pointy I agree, I've never used keyCode myself. This code just helps debug his issue by letting us know whether it's a browser issue or whether his JS fails beforehand.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. It would also illustrate exactly why it doesn't work for the OP I guess.

Comment: I'm catching the key correctly. The problem is browser is not refreshing the page. But thanx, this might prove useful with other browsers.

Comment: @MadSysop ahhh, ok I see what you mean. Changing the refresh to `window.location.href = window.location.href;` works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use e.which instead:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 27) {
      window.location.href = document.URL;
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm catching the key correctly. The problem is browser is not refreshing the page. But thanx, this might prove useful with other browsers.

Comment: Just noticed you've added FF4 as the problem. I'll check my code in that this morning.

Answer (score -1):

May help you:

```
document.onkeydown = onKeyDown;
function onKeyDown(){
   if(event.keyCode == 13) location = "http://url.com"
}
```